# Is there any API to generate a JSON schema programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, api, json

More info: I am converting XML data using the eclipse org.eclipse.uml2 (and emf) packages to generate a JSON schema, and looking for a similar Java API that provides JSON schema semantics (like `addProperty(String name, String type, boolean required)`, not general JSON semantics.